# C Unknown type name 'my_structure'

Tags: c, gcc, struct

I have this code:

`main.h`

```
#ifndef MAINH
#define MAINH
...
#include "my_struct.h"
void some_func(my_structure *x);
...
#endif
```

and

`my_struct.h`

```
#ifndef UTILSH
#define UTILSH
...
#include "main.h"
...
typedef struct abcd {
    int a;
} my_structure;
...
#endif
```

but I'm getting this when I try to compile: `error: unknown type name ‘my_structure’`

Any idea why?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Because of how you've ordered your includes, the compiler sees `void some_func(my_structure *x);` before it sees `typedef struct abcd { int a; } my_structure;`.

Let's walk this through.

Assuming `my_struct.h` is processed first, we get the following sequence of events:

1. `UTILSH` is defined
2. `MAINH` is defined
3. Because `UTILSH` is already defined, we don't process `my_struct.h` again, so the typedef isn't processed
4. `void some_func(my_structure *x);` is processed.
5. *Now* the `typedef` is processed.

So after preprocessing, your compiler sees the following sequence of declarations:

```
...
void some_func(my_structure *x);
...
typedef struct abcd {...} my_structure;
```

Bad juju.  You either need a forward declaration of `my_structure` in `main.h`, or you need to break that circular dependency (which is the much preferred option).  Is there anything in `main.h` that `my_structure.h` actually uses?  If so, you will want to factor it out into a separate file that both `main.h` and `my_structure.h` include.

Comment: Yes, main.h includes everything my app needs. I guess I could refactor/clean my code. I just wasn't sure it was because of that

Answer (score 11):

You created a circular header inclusion. Circular inclusion never achieves anything. It is infinite. The `#ifndef` include guard will break the infinite inclusion circle at some unpredictable point (depending on which header is included into `.c` file first).  This is what happened in your case. Basically, your circular inclusion got "resolved" into including `main.h` first and `my_struct.h` second. This is why `main.h` knows nothing about `my_struct` type.

Again, circular inclusion never achieves anything. Get rid of circular inclusion. Design your header structure hierarchically: lower-level headers included into higher-level headers, but never the other way around. In your case `my_struct.h` is probably a lower-level header, which means that you have to stop including `main.h` into `my_struct.h`. Redesign your headers so that `my_struct.h` no longer needs  `main.h`.

Comment: "break [...] inclusion circle at some **unpredictable point**" : Thanks for that detail. Exactly the part I was missing to understand.

Answer (score 4):

The error message is coming from `main.h` while it's included in `my_struct.h`, before `my_structure` is defined. You should rethink your include paths since `main.h` and `my_struct.h` include each other.

You probably want your `main.h` file to just include `my_struct.h`, and not have `my_struct.h` to include anything. You're essentially instructing your C compiler to have an infinite co-include loop.

Comment: But isn't supposed ```MAINH``` to protect me from this?

Comment: It will protect you from including it twice, but you're still including `main.h` from `my_struct.h` when I believe you intend to do the opposite.

Comment: @alexandernst You should put the includes outside the ifndef directive to work as you expected

Comment: @alexandernst: It *does* protect you from infinite inclusion. But the error you are getting is a direct consequence of that "protection".