# What is wrong with this? C

Tags: c, types, header-files

I'm having trouble finding my error. Here is a definition in `structures.h`

```
typedef struct book {
  bank_account_t **accounts;
  transaction_t **transactions;
} book_t;
```

And here is in `functions.c` where I include header and try to use the type `book_t`

```
#include "structures.h"

void load_book(book_t *book) {

}
```

But I get this error

```
functions.c:10:16: error: unknown type name ‘book_t’
 void load_book(book_t *book) {
                ^
```

Edits with more code below:

In my `main` file I order my `.h` files like so

```c
#include "structures.h"
#include "functions.h"
```

`structures.h`

```c
#ifndef STRUCTURES_H
# define STRUCTURES_H


typedef struct bank_account {
  char *name;
  int amount;
} bank_account_t;

typedef struct transaction {
  char *name;
  int amount;
} transaction_t;

typedef struct book {
  bank_account_t **accounts;
  transaction_t **transactions;
} book_t;

#endif
```

`function.c`

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#include "functions.h"
#include "structures.h"
#include "bank_account.h"
#include "transaction.h"

void load_book(book_t *book) {

}

void init_book() {

}
```

`bank_account.h`

```c
#ifndef BANK_ACCOUNT_H
# define BANK_ACCOUNT_H

void init_new_bank();
void deinit_new_bank();

#endif
```

`transaction.h`

```c
#ifndef TRANSACTION_H
# define TRANSACTION_H

#endif
```

Comment: isnt book_t only valid in the structures.h ?

Comment: very wierd... is there more information? how are you building the program?  and please post the whole `structures.h`...

Comment: Show the whole program. When I compile it with gcc as a  C file it works fine, as it should. Where are the definitions for bank_account and transaction?

Comment: You propably copypasted the header file from another header you use and forgot to adjust the header-guards?

Comment: looks like this might same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903300/c-unknown-type-name-my-structure

Comment: @Devolus please delete that comment, there is nothing as c mode, it's a c compler or g++ a c++ compiler, it's just that gcc uses the file extension to guess which compiler to use...

Comment: @alk that's exactly what I was thinking of...

Comment: @alk Great suggestion. I just checked and they are correct. I'll update the post with more info

Comment: @user1627167 I actually checked this out before posting this and checked to make sure this wasn't happening to me. Nice guess though

Comment: Maybe you have a different includefile which the compiler finds first and includes instead of your file? Rename the file tomsomehting like MyBook.h and see if it also happens.

Comment: For debugging purpose include a `#error choke` or just some garbage in the line after the definition of `book_t` and see whether the compiler chokes on it.

Comment: Question is in grey shade. Need some more information.

Comment: All downvoters: This is a beginner's debugging problem. So it is diffcult to provide more info because if the OP knew where to look s/he would not have come here.

Comment: Please also show functions.h

Comment: @waterdowner does `typedef struct book book_t;` right before `load_book()`'s definition wokr?

Comment: Guys I found the problem, I'm too embarrassed to say. So sorry for wasting your time. Thank you to everyone!

Comment: @waterdowner, not posting the solution is in my opinion reude, because for others with a similar problem they are left in the dark.

Comment: My solution was realizing I was editing the wrong `structure.h` file. MAKE SURE YOU ARE WORKING ON THE CORRECT FILES!!

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem must be in functions.h (which is not included in the original post).

`functions.h`

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H
# define FUNCTIONS_H

/* [MarkU] required: include definition of book_t */
#include "structures.h"

void load_book(book_t *book);
void init_book();

#endif
```

Without the `#include structures.h` there is no definition of the boot_t type.

Built and verified with mingw32-gcc 4.7.2.  Omitting the #include, I see the error message.

Answer (score 2):

In `functions.c` change the order of those:

```
#include "functions.h"
#include "structures.h"
```

to be

```
#include "structures.h"
#include "functions.h"
```

The subtile thing is that the error message origins from `functions.c` not from `functions.h`.

Assuming the protoytpe to `load_book(book_t *)` in `functions.h`, it needs to know about `book_t`.

So the optimal solution to this would be to include `structures.h` into `functions.h` (as also already pointed out by [*MarkU*'s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2427089/marku) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28779479/694576)).

**Lesson learned**: Always (and only) include what you need and where you need it. Avoid (subtile) dependencies.

Comment: That would be my guess as well.

Comment: Didn't work. `structures.h` is the first header I call and it doesn't include `functions.h`

Comment: @waterdowner: Please note that the error you show does not origin from compiling `main.c` but from compiling `functions.c` so the order of includes in `main.c` does not matter at all.

Comment: @alk Yup sorry, just caught that. But I'm still getting the same error :(

Comment: @waterdowner: Just delete all .o files and recompile after applying the change I propose.

Comment: I found the problem. Too embarrassed to say :( hahaha. Thank you so much for the help

Comment: @waterdowner: I bet you also had an (unmaintained) `function_with_no_trailing_s.h` lying around, hadn't you? ;-)

Comment: @alk haha no it wasn't that either! I was editing the wrong `structures.h` file...